# Loading a webpage

Tags: java, android, webview

I am new to Android and I want to load a web page which is at an URL (ie http://www.bhaskar.com/article/INT-sri-lanka-emergency-laws-to-end-2-years-after-war%E2%80%8E-2381626.html).

It contains Hindi data. I am loading this webpage by using `loadUrl(url)` method but it is loading the square boxes in the WebView. I have to give the font that is Hindi.

Please suggest me the steps how to load this webpage into my WebView application. I have tried this for a long time but no results. I am eagerly awaiting your answers.

For any help: Thanks in Advance!

---

My current source code is:

```
public class WebviewDemo extends Activity {

    public static String URL = "http://www.bhaskar.com/article/INT-sri-lanka-emergency-laws-to-end-2-years-after-war%E2%80%8E-2381626.html";


    WebView ArticleView;
    String htmlsting=null,head=null;
     Typeface typeface;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "DroidHindi.ttf");
        //head="<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'typeface';src: url('file:///android_asset/DroidHindi.ttf');}</style></head>";
        //htmlsting="<html>"+head+"<body font-family: 'typeface'></body></html>";
    //  htmlsting ="<html><head><style>@font-face {font-family:'typeface';src: url('file:///android_asset/DroidHindi.ttf');}</style></head><body 'style=font-family:typeface';></body></html>";                         
            System.out.println("***************URL is:****************"+URL);   
        ArticleView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Article_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = ArticleView.getSettings();
        ArticleView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        ArticleView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

        ArticleView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        try { 

   ArticleView.loadUrl(URL);           

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }   
    /*
     * 
     * Closes the WebView
     */
    public void cancelActivity(View v) {
        ArticleView.clearCache(true);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your source code currently look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is seems right !
Make Sure that You are using real device or emulator for application.
You have to Install Hindi font for Emulator/Device then you will be able to see proper hindi font instead of square boxes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to imeplement it like this

```
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.watchClipWebView);

            final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
            settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

            final Activity activity = this;
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                }

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, failingUrl + "\n" + description,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    handlePageLoaded();
                }


            });

            webView.loadUrl(sUrl);
}
    private void handlePageLoaded() {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

in short you misseed the webView.setWebViewClient + webView.setWebChromeClient

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

You shouldn't need to add a font - the page pulls in the font's itself (Look in Chrome DevTools > Resources Tab > Fonts)

http://www.bhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/font_family/Bhaskar_Web_Head_Test_exp.ttf
http://www.bhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/font_family/Bhaskar_WEB_Intro_Test_ship.ttf

Ensure you have the internet permission in your manifest:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```